# search inside xml

Tags: java, android, xml, search

I want to implement search in may android app
data is stored in XML files
a straightforward way to this is parsing every file and search in it
I'm using xmlpull

any faster approach?

Comment: The faster approach depends on the type and the nature of data. Wat are you search? Strings? Substrings?

Comment: yes strings like this <content>text to be searched</content>

Answer (score 0):

If you perform a full text match you can avoid xml and put the strings in a 
plain text file into the asset folder.
Strings could be sorted since they are stored statically into the file. 
With a sorted array of strings you can perform a binary search which is 
really fast if the number of the strings is not too high.

If the number of strings is very high you could split strings into several
file, for instance A-C.txt D-F.txt and so on

Comment: xml are ideal data vectors and it's count is high may reach 50k files ;trouble !!

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert it into something other than XML, like a database that is searchable.
2. If you are searching with in a single XML doc, you could read it in and use XPath to search the nodes.
3. Just treat the xml as text and do a string search over all of it.